# Wordpress CSS element for posts and pages

Tags: css, wordpress

My pages and posts use the same *.post p* element in style.css for some reason. I'm trying to change the line-height only for the blog posts but I don't know how to separate them.

This is a blog post: http://www.crossfitawac.com/onramp-6/

CSS: http://pastebin.com/tkuUhFY1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posts and pages will have a different body selector.

for pages line height use the following:

```
body.page .post p{
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

for posts use the following:

```
body.single .post p{
      line-height: 1.6;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, that works for changing the line-heights individually. my problem however seems to be that my posts are automatically published from a website called Wodify and they come with line breaks between each row. On Wodify I don't have any option to customize this, I only login with the wordpress credentials. For example this is what I get in a post: http://pastebin.com/Z0PtJHyP  While I can customize h3 for example in the style.css, I guess I cannot make it post with the line breaks removed.

Comment: just change the margin-bottom in the p element, WordPRess wraps line breaks in paragraphs. the spaces that you see is the bottom margin of the paragraph.